# JQuery selector selecting GridView paging

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, jquery-selectors

I've got the selector below:

```
$("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> td:nth-child(5)").hover('doSomething)
```

Which is selecting the 5th td that is generated by a GridView.  This is working fine.

My problem is I have paging enabled, and its also selecting the < Prev 1 2 3 Next > at the bottom, any ideas how to exclude this?

Comment: I tried both answers and they both worked.  However I gave Jamie the points as it looked simpler and he has less points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the HTML output you will see the paging elements are in a nested table, so just be a little more defined with your selector:

```
$("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5)").hover('doSomething)
```

Answer (score 1):

modify your selector to select the 5th `<td>`s in all rows except for the last one, assuming the paging is inside the last `<tr>`

try:

`$("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr:not(:last-child) td:nth-child(5)").hover(doSomething)`